# My canvas is changing position when I drag it

Tags: tkinter

This is my class that allows the user to drag the canvas.

```python
class WindowDraggable():

    def __init__(self, label):
        self.label = label
        label.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', self.StartMove)
        label.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.StopMove)
        label.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.OnMotion)

    def StartMove(self, event):
        self.x = event.x
        self.y = event.y

    def StopMove(self, event):
        self.x = None
        self.y = None

    def OnMotion(self, event):
        x = (event.x_root - self.x - self.label.winfo_rootx() 
                                   + self.label.winfo_rootx())
        y = (event.y_root - self.y - self.label.winfo_rooty() 
                                   + self.label.winfo_rooty())
        root.geometry("+%s+%s" % (x, y))
```

However, as soon as I click and hold the label, the subsequent motion adjusts the position of the canvas so that the cursor is positioned on the top left of the canvas. You can see where the cursor is in this image.

[image]

I thought to solve this problem using the recommendation to set the cursor position manually like this

```python
def StartMove(self, event):

    self.x = event.x + 100
    self.y = event.y + 150
```

But the problem is that the label expands to touch both sides of the screen, so the cursor should simply remain in its originally position for aesthetic reasons. I found this function, thinking it would help to solve the problem, but I am a bit lost in how to use it.

```python
#sets mouse-cursor position
def click(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0)
```

This is my program in reduced form, showing only the essential part related to my question.

```python
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

#window creation
root = Tk()
root.overrideredirect(1)  # eliminates frame around window

#canvas creation
canvas = Canvas(root, width=width, height=height, bd=-2)
canvas.pack()

#sets mouse-cursor position
def click(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0)

#makes window draggable
class WindowDraggable():

    def __init__(self, label):
        self.label = label
        label.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', self.StartMove)
        label.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.StopMove)
        label.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.OnMotion)

    def StartMove(self, event):

        self.x = event.x + 100
        self.y = event.y + 150

    def StopMove(self, event):
        self.x = None
        self.y = None

    def OnMotion(self, event):
        x = (event.x_root - self.x - self.label.winfo_rootx() 
                                   + self.label.winfo_rootx())
        y = (event.y_root - self.y - self.label.winfo_rooty() 
                                   + self.label.winfo_rooty())
        root.geometry("+%s+%s" % (x, y))


#creates the draggable label
label = Label(root, text='drag me')
WindowDraggable(label)
label.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

#end of program
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your question mentions a canvas but your code doesn't show a canvas. This is just some code copied and pasted directly from another SO answer. Can you give us a complete working example that illustrates your problem?

Comment: @BryanOakley Ok, this is the entire code. Why am I being down-voted (again).

Comment: I downvoted your original question because you mention a problem without showing any research effort. The code you posted was not your code, it was cut and pasted from another post. Your question mentioned a canvas but the code didn't show a canvas. All of that makes for a very low quality question. Now you have the problem that you have too much code. The code that does the ping has nothing to do with moving the window around, so why include it? You should strive to make the smallest program possible that exhibits the problem you are having.

Comment: The reason we ask for a small working program is that, quite often, the effort you put into doing that allows you to discover for yourself what the problem is. The act of reducing the problem down often shines light on the problem, allowing you to solve your own problem.

Comment: @BryanOakley Ok fair enough, but I didn't post the rest of the code because I didn't think that it was relevant, and I still don't think it is. Also, I don't see what's wrong with posting another person's code if it's a legitimate question.

Comment: @BryanOakley Ok, that is a valid point I hadn't thought of. But borrowing someones code from another post though, isn't wrong, and asking how it works isn't either.

Comment: You are correct: a lot of the code is _not_ relevant. You need to take the time to remove all irrelevant code while preserving the code that causes the problem. This is as important to you as it is to us, because it helps you understand which part of your code is causing the problem.

Comment: correct: borrowing someone else's code isn't wrong. Though, if the code came from a SO answer and the code isn't working, the best thing to do is ask for clarification from the original answer. The fact that you copied and pasted the code without mentioning that says to me that you haven't taken the time to understand it.

Comment: @BryanOakley Ok, thanks for the advice. What do you think of my question now that I have edited it? It is worth reading or is it bothersome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to make it so that when you set the new position of the canvas, you need to take away half the width of the canvas from the x, and add half the height of the canvas to the why:

```
def StartMove(self, event):
    self.x = event.x - (width / 2)
    self.y = event.y + (height / 2)
```

Comment: This almost solves my problem. Any idea why I can't use division without getting an error? Adding and subtracting appear to work.

Comment: @user4261180 Realised I forgot the division in my answer. Did you lay it out this way? If so, what was the error?

Comment: No I didn't lay it out that way although I thought I tried to use parenthesis. I'm sure it will work your way, but now that I have expanded the label so that the user had a larger surface area to click and drag, I would rather that the cursor remain in the same place rather than re position to the center of the label (if that makes any sense). You can see what I mean in the edited question...